# 'str' object has no attribute 'h264'

Tags: performance, raspberry-pi, python-3.5

trying to do rasp. pi project "parent detector". fixed error with camera. now having an error i have 0 idea how to fix.

already had camera error fixed. old raspberry pi model. don't know what model. looked at project site and at answers and there shouldn't be an error. 
entire error says:

```
  filename= "{0:%Y}-{0:%m}-{0:%d}.h264
Attribute Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'h264'
```

this is the code for the project.

```
from gipiozero import MotionSensor
import picamera
from datetime import datetime

pir=MotionSensor(4)

while True:
    filename= "{0:%Y}-{0:%m}-{0:%d}.h264
    pir.wait_for_motion()
    camera.start_recording(filename)
    pir.wait_no_motion()
    camera.stop_recording()
```

expected a motion detecting camera. got errors. gave up, teacher is forcing me to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the line:

```
filename= "{0:%Y}-{0:%m}-{0:%d}.h264
```

you almost *certainly* should have a closing `"` at the end. However, given the error, I'm pretty certain what you *actually* have is something like:

```
filename= "{0:%Y}-{0:%m}-{0:%d}".h264
```

which would cause you to try and access the `h264` property of that string:

```
>>> "{0:%Y}-{0:%m}-{0:%d}".h264
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'h264'
```

In addition, you are *probably* trying to construct a filename from a `datetime` object, and this can be done with:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> "{0:%Y}-{0:%m}-{0:%d}.h264".format(dt.now())
'2019-06-11.h264'
```